Ubuntu 22.04.4 installation/boot error
I'm trying to install Ubuntu 22.04.4 through Wubiuefi alongside an existing windows 10 installation.
Wubiuefi is a program that can be found here: https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi
I launched the installer, chose Ubuntu and gave it 256GB , created a username and password and proceeded with download of the system. After that, the installer asked to reboot, which is what I did. My laptop rebooted and started installing Ubuntu. The installation went smoothly . But the laptop rebooted again, this time though, it kept giving me this error screen:
error]1]1
I wanted to use this Wubiuefi installer because I didn't want to fiddle with partitions and possibly mess up the current windows 10 installation.
I should note that I also tried installing Kubuntu and Edubuntu from the Wubiuefi installer and I got the same error screen...
Can someone help me with this please?
Thanks in advance!

You do realize you're selecting an older ISO of 22.04; ie. Ubuntu 22.04.5 is the latest of the older 2022-April release of Ubuntu, which is available for all products (Server, Desktop etc) and flavors.  I don't know the app you're using so can't comment there sorry.
